# Proof verification for $\sup A \leq \inf B$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let A and B be two sets such that $a \leq b$ for every $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$. We aim to prove that $\sup A \leq \inf B$.

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\sup A > \inf B$. Then, there exists $b_1 \in B$ such that $\sup A > b_1$. Since $a \leq b_1$ for every $a$ in $A$, $b_1$ is an upper bound for $A$. However, $b_1 < \sup A$, contradicting the definition of $\sup A$ as the least upper bound of $A$. Thus, our assumption $\sup A > \inf B$ must be false, leading to the conclusion that $\sup A \leq \inf B$.

Therefore, we have shown that $\sup A \leq \inf B$.

Comment: Contradiction is a good idea. Hint : make a drawing. "Then, there exists b1∈B such..." is not clear : prove it.

Comment: It seemed pretty intuitive, but I am not sure how would I go about proving that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose  $\sup A>\inf B$ :
[image]
Let $\epsilon :=\sup A - \inf B$

By definition of $\inf $ and $\sup$ $$\exists b_1 \in B,a_1\in A \text{ such that }\inf B\leq b_1<\inf B+\frac {\epsilon}{2}<a_1\leq \sup A$$

Then $$b_1<a_1$$This leads us to a contradiction.$\square$

Comment: Thanks a lot, choosing epsilon as the difference between the supremum and infimum is neat.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a direct proof without contradiction.

Suppose any $b\in B$ is given. Since $a\le b$ for every $a\in A$, $b$ is un upper bound of $A$. Thus $\sup A\le b$ by definition of $\sup$. Since this holds for any $b\in B$, $\sup A$ is a lower bound of $B$. Thus $\sup A\le\inf B$ by definition of $\inf$.

Comment: I know, I just thought of that first and wanted to check if it's true.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Your proof looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.